# No resource error while trying to build Heartbeat app

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to make an app that gets my heartbeat from my wear watch, and then sends it to a server. I'm trying to use upost's Heartbeat app as a base ( https://github.com/upost/MyHeartbeat ), but I keep getting these errors:

[image: Build Errors]

What kind of errors are these?

Comment: What's your target SDK version?  If not 23, up it to 23.  You're using attributes that don't exist before then.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the first 4 issues, but I still have this error: Execution failed for task ':wear:processReleaseResources'.         >com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Android\Sds\build-tools\22.0.0\aapt.exe" finished with a non-zero exit value 1

Comment: I've solved this as well, didn't see that there were two gradle.build entries, one for the mobile and one for the wear, and the wear still had the 22.0.0 build tools. Changed it to 23.0.4 and it worked.